# ternary operator in vba excel throws error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to add this line of code in vba excel for custom function

```
(days > 0 ? days + ' day' + (days > 1 ? 's' : '') + ' ' : '') + hours+':'+minutes+':'+Math.round(seconds)
```

This is my first function in vba excel. Its showing the statement in red color. Does excel 2013 support this ?

Comment: This is not proper VBA syntax. You'll have to convert to proper syntax from whatever language this is.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman this is from my javascript function. I modified the Round.Math from Math.Round(), except that its a working syntax. My bad didn't include `(` at the beginning. `+` in replaced with `&`

Comment: For VBA - just use `Round` ... `Round(seconds)`.

Comment: vba does not do IF/THEN statements in this format.  You litteraly need to type in the IF, Then, Else ... and break it apart.

Comment: You should also add `javascript` and `excel` to your tags since you are coding in `javascript` and not `vba`

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I have converted the javascript function which is working fine and migrated into excel for export purpose.

Comment: That's not valid syntax in *any* language I'm aware of. The parens are unbalanced and you don't have a false condition for the outer nested ternary.  Whatever the intent of the code is, I would guess that building a custom string for `Format$` would be simpler in VBA.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work...

You may need to use CStr(hours) etc depending on how you've Dim'd the variables

```
If Days > 0 Then
    var = Days & Iff(Days > 1, " days ", " day ") & hours & ":" & minutes & ":" & Round(seconds)
End If
```

EDIT:

To reflect altered question...

```
Iff(Days > 0, Days & Iff(Days > 1, " days : ", " day : "), "") & hours & ":" & minutes & ":" & Round(seconds)
```